# Capturing LinearLayout onClick events with ImageButton inside it

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton, onclicklistener

I have an ImageButton and a TextView wrapped in a LinearLayout like this:

```
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20" android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true" android:id="@+id/action_showhide">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_toggle_hide_states" android:background="@null"></ImageButton>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtHide"
            android:textColor="@drawable/orange" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The ImageButton is backed by a custom drawable for normal, focused and pressed states.  I would like to allow the user to click anywhere in the LinearLayout to fire an OnClick event.   The code below shows the set up for the OnClickListener:

```
    final LinearLayout actionHide = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.action_showhide);
    actionHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(AppAdvocate.TAG, "Event caught");
        }
    });
```

The code works when the user clicks anywhere on the TextView but when the user clicks on the ImageButton the event doesn't bubble up to the LinearLayout.  I am not defining an onClickListener for the button.  I want the drawable for my ImageButton to change so I don't want to set it to clickable=false.  Is there a way to bubble up the event?

Answer (score 4):

In order to make `LinearLayout` clickable you need to set `android:focusable="false"` on all its child elements.

Comment: I set all child "android:focusable=false",but LinearLayout still unclickable

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to make the button not clickable, you could just add a listener to the button and perform the same action as the LinearLayout onClick.  It would appear to the user as if it was one big button.

Comment: Thanks Mayra, this works.  How should I cascade the LinearLayout onClick event down to the ImageButton so that its drawable changes state when the LinearLayout is pressed?

Comment: I'm not sure what state you are referring to.  Does the image button act like a Toggle button, where it shows a clicked state?  You should be able to just call setChecked(checkedState) on your toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, you'll be needing the following:

```
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20" android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true" android:id="@+id/action_showhide">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_toggle_hide_states" android:background="@null">         </ImageButton>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtHide"
            android:textColor="@drawable/orange" android:textStyle="bold"
android:onClick="viewClicked"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

After that, you create the function:

```
public void viewClicked(View v){

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.action_showhide:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.action_showhide:
            //do something
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set android::clickable="false" on ImageButton. This should help.

Comment: no, please read the question: "so I don't want to set it to clickable=false"